# Xquery for finding cousins in an xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I am new to xquery and I am looking for a quick solution to this problem.

I have an xml document, and I want to find all pairs of first cousins and all pairs of 2nd cousins in the documents.

Please have a look a the the xml below and guide me how to proceed or if you can provide any code snippet that will be highly appricieated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE GEDCOM SYSTEM "file:/Users/indiwarafernando/Downloads/family.dtd">
<GEDCOM>
    <HeaderRec>
        <FileCreation Date=""></FileCreation>
        <Submitter>
            <Link Target="" Ref="FM001"/> 
        </Submitter>
    </HeaderRec>
    <FamilyRec Id="FM001">
        <HusbFath>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN001"/>
        </HusbFath>
        <WifeMoth>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN002"/>
        </WifeMoth>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
        </Child>

        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
        </Child>

    </FamilyRec>


    <FamilyRec Id="FM002">
        <HusbFath>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
        </HusbFath>
        <WifeMoth>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN005"/>
        </WifeMoth>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN006"/>
        </Child>

    </FamilyRec>  



    <FamilyRec Id="FM003">
        <HusbFath>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
        </HusbFath>
        <WifeMoth>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN008"/>
        </WifeMoth>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN009"/>
        </Child>

    </FamilyRec> 

    <IndividualRec Id="IN001">
        <IndivName>Fathers name</IndivName>                 <!-- This tag used for father of c1 or husband of w1 -->
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="" Ref="IN002"/>
            <Association>Wife</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>

    <IndividualRec Id="IN002">                                 <!-- This tag used for mother of c1 or wife of h1 -->
        <IndivName>Mother s name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN001"/>
            <Association>Husband</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>

    <IndividualRec Id="IN003">                                  <!-- This tag used for a child to h1 or w1 or grand son to gm1 or gf1 -->
        <IndivName>Child 1 name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN001"/>
            <Association>Father</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN002"/>
            <Association>Mother</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>




    <IndividualRec Id="IN005">                                 <!-- This tag used for grand mother -->
        <IndivName>Grand mother's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
            <Association>Husband</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>

    <IndividualRec Id="IN004">                                  <!-- This tag used for grand father -->
        <IndivName>Grand father's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN005"/>
            <Association>Grand Father's Wife</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>

    <IndividualRec Id="IN006">                                  <!-- This tag used for a child to h1 or w1 or grand son to gm1 or gf1 -->
        <IndivName>Child 1 name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
            <Association>Father</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN005"/>
            <Association>Mother</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>



    <IndividualRec Id="IN007">                                 <!-- This tag used for grand mother -->
        <IndivName>Grand mother's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN008"/>
            <Association>Husband</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>

    <IndividualRec Id="IN008">                                  <!-- This tag used for grand father -->
        <IndivName>Grand father's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
            <Association>Grand Father's Wife</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>

    <IndividualRec Id="IN009">                                  <!-- This tag used for a child to h1 or w1 or grand son to gm1 or gf1 -->
        <IndivName>Child 1 name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
            <Association>Father</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN008"/>
            <Association>Mother</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>



</GEDCOM>
```

**Example Output: **
An example output of a pair of first cousin is
IN006 and IN009

Regards
Fareed

Comment: Please add homework tag if this is the case.

Comment: No, please don't. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. This XSLT 2.0 transformation (can easily be re-written into XSLT 1.0) produces all first cousins**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my xs">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="Child"
  use="../HusbFath/*/@Ref"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="Child"
  use="../WifeMoth/*/@Ref"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="FamilyRec">
  <xsl:variable name="vGrandChildren" select=
   "my:GrandChildren((HusbFath|WifeMoth)
                            [string(*/@Ref)][1]
                              /*/@Ref
                     )
   "/>
   <xsl:sequence select=
    "for $first in 1 to count($vGrandChildren),
         $second in $first+1 to count($vGrandChildren),
         $grand1 in $vGrandChildren[$first],
         $grand2 in $vGrandChildren[$second]
      return
         if(not($grand1/.. is $grand2/..))
           then (concat('[', $grand1/*/@Ref, ',', $grand2/*/@Ref, '] '))
           else ()
    "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>

 <xsl:function name="my:GrandChildren">
  <xsl:param name="pRef" as="xs:string?"/>

   <xsl:sequence select=
   "key('kChildren',
        key('kChildren', $pRef, $vDoc)/Link/@Ref,
        $vDoc)
   "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<GEDCOM>
    <HeaderRec>
        <FileCreation Date=""></FileCreation>
        <Submitter>
            <Link Target="" Ref="FM001"/>
        </Submitter>
    </HeaderRec>
    <FamilyRec Id="FM001">
        <HusbFath>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN001"/>
        </HusbFath>
        <WifeMoth>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN002"/>
        </WifeMoth>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
        </Child>
    </FamilyRec>
    <FamilyRec Id="FM002">
        <HusbFath>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
        </HusbFath>
        <WifeMoth>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN005"/>
        </WifeMoth>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN006"/>
        </Child>
    </FamilyRec>
    <FamilyRec Id="FM003">
        <HusbFath>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
        </HusbFath>
        <WifeMoth>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN008"/>
        </WifeMoth>
        <Child>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN009"/>
        </Child>
    </FamilyRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN001">
        <IndivName>Fathers name</IndivName>
        <!-- This tag used for father of c1 or husband of w1 -->
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="" Ref="IN002"/>
            <Association>Wife</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN002">
        <!-- This tag used for mother of c1 or wife of h1 -->
        <IndivName>Mother s name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN001"/>
            <Association>Husband</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN003">
        <!-- This tag used for a child to h1 or w1 or grand son to gm1 or gf1 -->
        <IndivName>Child 1 name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN001"/>
            <Association>Father</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN002"/>
            <Association>Mother</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN005">
        <!-- This tag used for grand mother -->
        <IndivName>Grand mother's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
            <Association>Husband</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN004">
        <!-- This tag used for grand father -->
        <IndivName>Grand father's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN005"/>
            <Association>Grand Father's Wife</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN006">
        <!-- This tag used for a child to h1 or w1 or grand son to gm1 or gf1 -->
        <IndivName>Child 1 name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN004"/>
            <Association>Father</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN005"/>
            <Association>Mother</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN007">
        <!-- This tag used for grand mother -->
        <IndivName>Grand mother's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN008"/>
            <Association>Husband</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN008">
        <!-- This tag used for grand father -->
        <IndivName>Grand father's name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
            <Association>Grand Father's Wife</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
    <IndividualRec Id="IN009">
        <!-- This tag used for a child to h1 or w1 or grand son to gm1 or gf1 -->
        <IndivName>Child 1 name</IndivName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN007"/>
            <Association>Father</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
        <AssocIndiv>
            <Link Target="IndividualRec" Ref="IN008"/>
            <Association>Mother</Association>
        </AssocIndiv>
    </IndividualRec>
</GEDCOM>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
[IN006,IN009]
```

---

**II. To test if two `Child` elements are second cousins, add to the above this** (and add the necessary code to test for every pair of `Child`, whether they are second cousins:

```
 <xsl:key name="kGrandParent" match="HusbFath | WifeMoth"
  use="my:GrandChildren(Link/@Ref)/*/@Ref"/>

 <xsl:function name="my:areFirststCousins" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="pPers1" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPers2" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "key('kGrandParent', $pPers1/*/@Ref, $vDoc)[1]
  is
   key('kGrandParent', $pPers2/*/@Ref, $vDoc)[1]
  and
   not($pPers1/.. is $pPers2/..)
  "/>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:function name="my:areSecondCousins" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="pPers1" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPers2" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "my:areFirststCousins($pPers1/../(HusbFath|WifeMoth)[1],
                        $pPers2/../(HusbFath|WifeMoth)[1]
                       )
  "/>
 </xsl:function>
```

---

**III. The complete solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my xs">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="Child"
  use="../HusbFath/*/@Ref"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="Child"
  use="../WifeMoth/*/@Ref"/>

 <xsl:key name="kGrandParent" match="HusbFath | WifeMoth"
  use="my:GrandChildren(Link/@Ref)/*/@Ref"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  First Cousins:
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "for $first in 1 to count(/*/FamilyRec/Child),
       $second in $first+1 to count(/*/FamilyRec/Child),
       $pers1 in (/*/FamilyRec/Child)[$first],
       $pers2 in (/*/FamilyRec/Child)[$second]
     return
       if(my:areFirststCousins($pers1, $pers2))
         then concat('[', $pers1/*/@Ref, ',', $pers2/*/@Ref, '] ')
         else ()
  "/>

  Second Cousins:
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "for $first in 1 to count(/*/FamilyRec/Child),
       $second in $first+1 to count(/*/FamilyRec/Child),
       $pers1 in (/*/FamilyRec/Child)[$first],
       $pers2 in (/*/FamilyRec/Child)[$second]
     return
       if(my:areSecondCousins($pers1, $pers2))
         then concat('[', $pers1/*/@Ref, ',', $pers2/*/@Ref, '] ')
         else ()
  "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:GrandChildren">
  <xsl:param name="pRef" as="xs:string?"/>

   <xsl:sequence select=
   "key('kChildren',
        key('kChildren', $pRef, $vDoc)/Link/@Ref,
        $vDoc)
   "/>
 </xsl:function>


 <xsl:function name="my:areFirststCousins" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="pPers1" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPers2" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "key('kGrandParent', $pPers1/*/@Ref, $vDoc)[1]
  is
   key('kGrandParent', $pPers2/*/@Ref, $vDoc)[1]
  and
   not($pPers1/.. is $pPers2/..)
  "/>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:function name="my:areSecondCousins" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="pPers1" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPers2" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "my:areFirststCousins($pPers1/../(HusbFath|WifeMoth)[1],
                        $pPers2/../(HusbFath|WifeMoth)[1]
                       )
  "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same provided XML document (above), the correct result is produced**:

```
  First Cousins:
  [IN006,IN009] 

  Second Cousins:
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre,

This is definitely a detailed solution of my problem, but I realized that I was not quite clear at the first time and I mistakenly included the "xslt" tag while posting my problem.

Actually I am looking for a solution in the form of "Xquery". I am trying to convert the provided solution to xquery but I know I would take a lot of time successfully make this conversion.

If you could provide this solution in XQuery that will be much helpful.

Again thank you very much for looking into it and providing such a detailed solution.

Best Regards

Comment: Fareed, I think you should attempt the conversion yourself, unless you can point to a specific difficulty where you need help. Dimitre is very generous with his time, but the purpose of forums like this is to help people get up the learning curve, not to do their job for them.

Comment: @Fareed, I tend to agree with the comment by Michael Kay. When you have a working solution in XSLT, it should be quite easy to convert this in XQuery -- especially taking into account that templates aren't used in this solution. As for the "xslt" tag being specified "by mistake", I am sorry, but at the time I provided this answer, the question was tagged "xslt". Do you now want to simply disregard the work done to help you and solve the problem exactly as specified? My advice is not to try to mechanically convert this solution to XQuery, but to grasp the ideas and implement them in XQuery.

Comment: @Fareed, To translate this XSLT transformation into XQuery, you will just convert any `xsl:function` into an XQuery function. You will also convert the `xsl:key` definitions to XQuery functions. You will substitute any call to the `key()` function with a call to the corresponding XQuery function.